# Hardware performance penalty for Hyper-V Generation 2 VMs

Tags: performance, windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v, ssd

I have the following configuration:

- Windows Server 2012 R2 OS installed on baremetal with Hyper-V. OS is
  installed on RAID1 850 PRO drives.
- Windows Server 2012 R2 Guest OS Generation 2 VM is located on Windows Storage Space Mirrored 950 PRO drives.

I ran some tests on the Windows Storage Space Mirrored 950 PRO drives using 
Crystal Disk. These are the following stats.

When tested on baremetal

```
   Sequential Read (Q= 32,T= 1) :  4178.159 MB/s
  Sequential Write (Q= 32,T= 1) :  1504.286 MB/s
  Random Read 4KiB (Q= 32,T= 1) :   460.155 MB/s [112342.5 IOPS]
 Random Write 4KiB (Q= 32,T= 1) :   266.983 MB/s [ 65181.4 IOPS]
         Sequential Read (T= 1) :  2042.397 MB/s
        Sequential Write (T= 1) :  1500.305 MB/s
   Random Read 4KiB (Q= 1,T= 1) :    40.059 MB/s [  9780.0 IOPS]
  Random Write 4KiB (Q= 1,T= 1) :    76.623 MB/s [ 18706.8 IOPS]
```

When tested in VM

```
   Sequential Read (Q= 32,T= 1) :  4635.549 MB/s
  Sequential Write (Q= 32,T= 1) :  1502.071 MB/s
  Random Read 4KiB (Q= 32,T= 1) :   181.225 MB/s [ 44244.4 IOPS]
 Random Write 4KiB (Q= 32,T= 1) :   110.272 MB/s [ 26921.9 IOPS]
         Sequential Read (T= 1) :  1624.129 MB/s
        Sequential Write (T= 1) :  1381.203 MB/s
   Random Read 4KiB (Q= 1,T= 1) :    24.528 MB/s [  5988.3 IOPS]
  Random Write 4KiB (Q= 1,T= 1) :    34.563 MB/s [  8438.2 IOPS]
```

I have nearly a 50% drop in performance on my Random Read/Writes. I retested a couple times to confirm values. Is this to be expected?

Comment: You are aware that regardless what loss you have on Hyper-V .... the random throughput numbers for the bare metal are already COMICALLY LOW?

Comment: @TomTom It is? I never tried Windows Storage Space Mirrored configuration or 950 PROs on windows server 2012 r2 before. I didn't know what to expect. What do you think it should be?

Comment: Check the spec numbers. Remember: Raid 1, both discs can read independent. And yes, storage spaces is slow - which is why everyone I know avoids it for this type of work. We all hope for Server 2016...

Comment: I'm not sure about the margin for error but Random Write 4KiB (Q= 1, T= 1) is 50% lower than what it's speced to be. I'll tried it without Windows Storage Spaces with similar results. I even tried on my spare 950 PRO drives with similar results. Not sure where the bottle neck is.

Comment: Also remember hyper-v is "never" T=1 - you normally have multiple VM's running around. But yeah, that is what I mean - your numbers look too low from the start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all it's a good idea to use DiskSPD rather than anything else. Just because Microsoft uses DiskSPD during their internal QA process.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/josebda/2014/10/13/diskspd-powershell-and-storage-performance-measuring-iops-throughput-and-latency-for-both-local-disks-and-smb-file-shares/

Second this is known issue with Hyper-V. It's even present in more or less the same way in Windows Server 2016. In a nutshell there's typically a 2x - 4x I/O performance drop if your underlying storage has very low latency. You can try a couple of workarounds to improve your conditions:

**Use multiple volumes.** Don't allocate multiple CSVs on top of a single virtual disk or namespace but rather make sure local mount points (if you run VMs right from DAS), CSVs or SMB3 shares end on top of a different logical volumes! You'll have to have a single VM with multiple VHD files or multiple VMs to "aggregate" combined performance this way. If you have one VM with a single attached VHD this approach won't help obviously.

**Use "middle man".** This is sort of an incremental improvement within the first approach listed. You get multiple logical volumes, wrap some Windows-based software-defined storage on top and allow it to aggregate I/O performance for your single VM with a single VHD attached. It can happen if you run single Oracle RAC or SQL Server VM and it's exactly the one you want high IOPS for.

**Disable I/O scheduler.** Set registry key ...

"HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\StorVSP\IOBalance\Enabled"

... to zero! P.S. Don't forget to reboot as nothing changes on-the-fly.

This one may or may not work. We get ±20% boost on a pair of Samsung 850 Pro SSDs in RAID0.

Hope something is going to work for you. Please update with your results for future lurkers :)

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on "middle man" approach? What SDS solutions would be a good practice apart from Storage Spaces itself? Can I combine Storage Spaces with a 3rd party SDS to boost performance/get redundancy/extra features? We have Samsung EVO's as well but in RAID 5 and would like to squeeze the maximum from them.